# How to get let inside a block when adding iterations to it?

Tags: javascript, variables, var, let

Imagine:

```
const arr = ['a','b','c'];
let num;
const incr = arr.map((el, i) => { 
 num += el; 
}
// num is undefined in incr
```

How to get `num` inside `incr` function so it can increment itself on each loop?

Trying to put `num` inside `incr` will not result in proper increments as it will be overwritten on each loop.

Shall I use `var` instead?

Comment: You don't need `num`, use `Array.prototype.reduce`

Comment: It's `undefined` because you never assign a value to it.

Comment: undefined in incr function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't initializing `num`, so its value is `undefined`.

```
const arr = ['a','b','c'];
let num = '';
arr.forEach((el, i) => { 
 num += el; 
});
```

This will get you `'abc'` in `num`.

However, the idiom of accumulating values is better served by `.reduce`:

```
const arr = ['a','b','c'];
const num = arr.reduce((acc, i) => acc + i);
```

and better yet, what you're doing here, i.e. joining an array to form a string, is served by `.join`:

```
const arr = ['a','b','c'];
const num = arr.join('');
```